# Set Div to 100% of Body

Tags: css, html, height

I have a div called 'main-container' that I want to be the height of my content. At the moment, the div is only as tall as my browser window. I've tried to correct this like so:

```
html, body{
  height: 100%;
  background-color: $main-background-color;
}

#main-container {
  width: 1024px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: darken($main-background-color, 5%);
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. I've also tried:

```
#main-container {
  width: 1024px;
  min-height: 100%;
  height:auto !important;
  background-color: darken($main-background-color, 5%);
}
```

This has no effect, either. I've also reworked my layout not use floats, but that didn't solve the problem. After scouring the net, I haven't found any other solutions that work. Does anyone else have an idea?

Also, I don't know if this would affect things, but I'm using Rails 3.

Comment: Hmm your css is current and should work. (But maybe the variables produces some content that screws up the css syntax?? Or #main-container is overridden later on? Or you need to clear your browser cache(probably not that)

Comment: When I inspect the element in Chrome or Firebug, it tells me that the height is being set to 100% by my main CSS file. Looks like nothing is interfering with it. However, I have found a partial (though unacceptable) fix. If I set 'overflow: auto', then the height gets set properly. Unfortunately, it causes problems with scroll bars. I'll keep experimenting with this, though. Perhaps it'll lead to the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the bottom of your `#main-container` div, insert the following code:

```
<div id="push"></div>
```

Then in your CSS, add the following:

```
#push {
    clear:both;
}
```

This should then push the whole container to the height of the content, regardless of floating divs.

Comment: Strangely, that doesn't work. Even if I remove all floating elements from my layout, the height still won't set properly. As I noted in the comment above, however, when I set 'overflow: auto' or 'overflow: hidden' the height will set properly--though it also leads to problems with hidden content or unwanted scroll bars.

Comment: @tbaron In that case, try `overflow:visible;`

Comment: Unfortunately, when I set 'overflow:visible' it no longer fixes the height.

Comment: @tbaron Strange. Can you create a [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) to demonstrate your issue?

Comment: I've got a jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9HMZ/1/). Since it's a Rails site, it doesn't translate perfectly to this format. Unfortunately, the error isn't expressing, but you'll at least be able to see my code.

Comment: @tbaron Without being able to see the exact problem, I can't say what the problem is exactly, but the code looks okay to me.

Comment: I've finally got an answer that works. Combining your initial tip with Theo's suggestion below, I was able to get the height to display properly. Basically, in addition to clearing the floats, I needed to remove all the instances where I manually set the height. I still don't get exactly why my site is being so particular about this, but at least it's working now. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I may be misunderstanding what you are trying to accomplish. But if all you want is for your div to be the height of the content, then simply do not declare a height...

```
html, body{
  background-color: $main-background-color;
}

#main-container {
  width: 1024px;
  background-color: darken($main-background-color, 5%);
}
```

Comment: Combining your tip with Spiritfyre's answer, I was able to get the site to work. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `min-height:100%` instead of `height` on html/body, as `height:100%` will limit its size to the viewport.
Your `main-container` should then be able to stretch it, when higher than the viewport.

```
html, body{
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: $main-background-color;
}

#main-container {
  width: 1024px;
  background-color: darken($main-background-color, 5%);
}
```